# Multiply two matrices using pipe

Tags: c, matrix, pipe

I want to write a program to multiply two matrices using pipe for each variable but my code doesn't work right.

What is wrong with it?

The child and parents aren't same; neither their column and row nor their variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int first[10][10], second[10][10], m[10][10];
int r1,r2,c1,c2;

struct mat
{
int i,j,r;
};

int writer(int fd[],struct mat l)
{
    usleep(300000);
    close(fd[0]);
    int y;
    for(y=0;y<c1;y++)
    {
        l.r+=first[l.i][y]*second[y][l.j];
    }
    write(fd[1], &l,sizeof(l));
    printf("child [%d][%d] write %d \n " ,l.i,l.j, l.r);
}

void reader(int fd[])
{
    struct mat p;
    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0],&p,sizeof(p));
    printf(" Parent [%d][%d] reads %d \n ",p.i,p.j, p.r);
    m[p.i][p.j]=p.r;
    usleep(3000000);
}
```

`main` function is:

```
int main()
{

int a,b,j,i;
int fd[2];
pid_t cp;
pipe(fd);
\\read two matrices

    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
         {
                cp=fork();      
                if(cp==0)
                {
                    printf("k\n");
                    struct mat m;
                    m.r=0;
                    m.i=i;
                    m.j=j;
                    writer(fd,m);
                }
                if(cp!=0)
                {
                    sleep(2);
                    reader(fd);
                }    
        }   
        return 0;
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first problem your program encounters is this: the for loops in main are not running (try putting a `printf("Entering For Loop")` below the first for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
```

This is because the index variable is being compared to the uninitialized `r1`, which is theoretically a "garbage" value, but in reality, since this is the first time that address is used, it is zero.  So the code in the for loop is never executed.  Make sure all your for loops follow this rule.

Answer (score 1):

In function `writer()` your for loop `for(y=0;y<c1;y++)` reads `c1` but `c1` has never been initialized. this results in *undefined behaviour*